# Bash array length - my code always gives 1 or 0 but should have infinite varaibility

Tags: bash, array

Yes similar questions have been asked, but none of those answers have shown me what I am missing here.

I think my problem is in not fully understanding what I am generating with my code...

```
      LOGFILE=$1
      ERROR=$2
      START_TIME=$3
      END_TIME=$4
      FILEDATE=$(echo "${NOW//-}")

      FINDSTR='10\.22\.*'

      GREP=/bin/zgrep

      for (( HOUR=START_TIME ; HOUR <= END_TIME ; HOUR++ )); do
        DATE=$(printf "$NOW %02d" $HOUR )

        echo
        printf "%02d:00\n" $HOUR

        ERRORSTORES=$($GREP "$ERROR" $( find /opt/logs/ -name $LOGFILE-$FILEDATE* |
                 grep $FINDSTR ) | grep "$DATE" | awk -F ' ' '{ print $4 }' |
                 awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){printf ("%s\t%d\n", i, a[i])}}')

        printf "Stores showing \"%s\": %d\n" "$ERROR" "${#ERRORSTORES[*]}"
        printf '%s\n' "${ERRORSTORES[@]}"
      done
```

I have tried to simplify the code for purposes of this post. I have replaced a large chunk of working code that gets command line input with simple VAR=$n assignments

My problem is with the line

```
`printf "Stores showing \"%s\": %d\n" "$ERROR" "${#ERRORSTORES[@]}"`
```

From everything I have been able to find her and on other sites, the `"${#array[@]}"` should give me a count of the elements in the array. But `"${#ERRORSTORES[@]}"` is always printing 1 or 0!

I suspect now that I am composing this question that my problem lies in the printf of my awk filter at the end of the `ERRORSTORES=$(...)` line. I am guessing that my printf ending with \n is giving me the output that I want (each element on a newline) but confusing the `"${#array[@]}"` pattern.

As I understand things, I need a null character instead of `\n` but so far I am not coming up with a way to replace \n with a null character. I have tried `\0` and `\n\0`. The first strings my output together on one big line. The second still gives me the one element per line that I want but also gives a count of 1.

Comment: `ERRORSTORES` is not an array. You assign to it with a command substitution. This will give it a _single_ value. It's unclear what you want this variable to contain.  Also, `bash` variables (arrays or ordinary ones) can't contain `\0`.

Comment: I suspect your problem is that you're not using array assignment syntax in `ERRORSTORES=` -- you need a surrounding pair of parenthesis.  Untested, otherwise.

Comment: EERORSTORES is supposed to be an array of IP addresses, grepped from our log files.  @Jeff Schaller, if I understand your comment, then `ERRORSTORES=$(...)` should be `ERRORSTORES=($(...))`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Jeff's comment lead me to:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449417/how-do-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-into-an-array

Comment: Write the whole thing in awk. or perl. or python.  or anything other than a shell loop that forks grep and awk and whatever else multiple times per iteration.  See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/7696).    BTW, perl would be a good choice because it has the `File::Find` module, which offers similar functionality to the `find` command.

Comment: I have gotten the script working thanks to earlier comments. @cas I will look into your suggestions next time I dive into that script. Thank you for the suggestion.